# With freeform_module_insert_end hook how to get the posted data

Tags: solspace-freeform

https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/extension_hooks/#freeform_module_insert_end

I am using the `freeform_module_insert_begin` hook which stores the data into the database but with the `freeform_module_insert_end` hook I am unable to get the data which I posted in the `freeform_module_insert_begin` hook.

Here is my code:

```
function email_this($field_input_data, $entry_id, $form_id){
if (ee()->extensions->active_hook('freeform_module_insert_end') === TRUE)
{
    ee()->extensions->universal_call(
    'freeform_module_insert_end',
    $field_input_data,
    $entry_id,
    $form_id,
    $this
    );
} else {
    //else
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire `$_POST` array should still be available inside that hook (though for security you should access it via `ee()->input->post()`).

But your code is incorrect (I can see how the docs are confusing there). What you've posted is their demonstration of how the hook appears *inside the module* - not an example of how to use the hook.

You need to first insert a row into `exp_extensions` which maps `freeform_module_insert_end` to your `email_this` function ([see docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html#activating-and-updating)). Then just write your function like so:

```
function email_this($field_input_data, $entry_id, $form_id, $freeform_object)
{
    // Do what you need to do in here
    // ee()->input->post('my_field_name') should be available here as well
}
```